# Ubuntu cannot play all the videos on yahoo

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, flash

I have latest Ubuntu installed, with firefox 3.6.3.

I have `flashplugin-installer` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed.

No other package concerning flash (gnash, swf) is installed.

I can play videos on youtube or some other sites, some even some videos on yahoo, but I cannot play [this video](http://sports.yahoo.com/video/player/feat/NHL_Highlights/20142255#feat/NHL_Highlights/20142255) (and some others) - the blue circle in the center (like loading...) keeps flashing forever.

Why can't I play it, and how to make it play?

**Added:**
I have the latest flash installed also 10,1,53,64.

If someone can play it on ubuntu, could you please post here your versions of ubuntu and firefox and also the installed packages connected with FF and flash.

May be I need some codecs beside the flash?

Comment: Check your flash player version; it's possible that you need Flash 10 to display this.

Comment: i can play it fine on Ubuntu 10.04, FF 3.6, Flash 10.1.53.64.  basic firefox and *flashplugin-installer* packages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The website was down for a bit for me.. it's back up now though and flash works fine. The problem could have been at yahoo's end.

Comment: Seems, like it really was. That video can be played now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command-line utility `youtube-dl` to rip the videos to .flv and then play them in `mplayer` or `vlc`.  `vlc` used to be able to just play youtube videos right from the URL, but I don't think that works any more.  All of those commands have eponymous packages available via `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `synaptic`, `adept`, etc.  Advantages include improved compatibility (ie with newer flash versions) and the fact that other apps can play flash video much more efficiently than the flash plugin.

This won't help you much with yahoo video or other sites besides youtube, but for other sites you can find a browser extension to download the `.flv`.

Comment: Thanks, but I can play videos from youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems playing videos in FF on ubuntu, though it doesn't seem to be specific videos - rather something in the plugin seems to get messed up.  If you restart FF, and go right to that video without loading anything else, do you still have a problem playing it?

Usually, even when FF can't play it Chrome for linux will be able to - you might want to try installing that to validate whether or not it's FF specific or Ubuntu related.

And an shot in the dark: When I tried to play the video, it displayed an ad first.  Could it be that you have [flash cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) disabled, or something else that's interfering with the ad?  I don't think adblock will affect the ability to play a video, it didn't for me in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it needs a later version of Flash than you have, to fix this, run the command `sudo apt-get update` to update to the latest version of all your programs, including Flash.

Answer (score 0):

The compiz fusion visual effects disables flash buttons and controls. It might also be preventing your video playback. Try disabling all visual effects and then see if it works.

System > Preferences > Appearance > Visual Effects

**Edit:**

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with Firefox 3.6.3. I have "Ubuntu Restricted Extras" installed. These are the the plugins I have in firefox that might be related:

DivX Web Player version 1.4.0.233
QuickTime Plug-in 7.6.6
Shockwave Flash 10.1 r53
VLC Multimedia Plugin (compatible Totem 2.30.2)
Windows Media Player Plug-in 10 (compatible; Totem)

I'd first try installing VLC.